# ProcessBuilder starting a .class file with parameters

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

So i have two files: Main.java and Second.java. I wanna work with processes using ProcessBuilder. With cmd i can write "javac Second.java" and "java Second 5". My Second.java looks like that

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Okay");
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(args[0])); // I need it just for checking
        System.exit( Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    }
```

My second process should return specific exit value (that's why i use System.exit() ).
I understood that ProcessBuilder is not a cmd. I tried to run it like that

```
   Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
   String curDir=currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
   curDir=curDir+"\\src";
   ProcessBuilder PB=new ProcessBuilder("java",curDir, "second", "5");
   try {
                Process process = PB.start();
                process.waitFor();
                System.out.println(process.exitValue());
            }catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

But that doesn't work.
I think i don't need to create class files exactly in my program i will create them later by cmd.
How can i give my ProcessBuilder String[] args, which i need in my Second.main()?

Comment: Why would you call other Java classes as separate processes rather than invoking them as Java APIs?

Comment: You are passing a directory name to `java`, which is not valid.  Did you forget a `"-cp"` argument?  Also, you are passing `"second"` with a lowercase `s`, which will fail if the class name is `Second` with an uppercase `S`.  And you can remove all of that code with `currentRelativePath` and just write `String curDir = "src";`, since all paths are either absolute or are implicitly relative to the current directory.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I'm a student, and this is my task. I need to create a project, in which user will enter some input parameters, and then my main starts two processes with this parameters. For example, user enters f 5 and then g 3. I need to start second two times (at the same time if it possible), first with parameters f 5, and second with g 3. In Second.java will be something like [ if (args[0]=="f"){does something} else if (args[0]=="g"){...} else exitvalue error]. Also i don't understood what you mean in "invoking them as Java APIs"

Comment: @VGR Oh, thank you, it works with "-cp", i will read about it. Can you post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing this command:  **java** *directory* **second 5**

That is not a valid invocation of the `java` command.  The syntax is:

`java` *[-options] class [args...]*

Passing a class name is correct.  Passing a directory is not correct.

You can see the syntax for yourself by running `java -h`, or by reading [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html).  No need to guess what is allowed.

What you *are* allowed to do is pass a directory as an argument to the `-cp` option, which is probably what you intended:

```
new ProcessBuilder("java", "-cp", curDir, "second", "5");
```

Be aware that class names are case sensitive.  If your class is named `Second`, you must pass the same name, with a capital `S`, to your java command:

```
new ProcessBuilder("java", "-cp", curDir, "Second", "5");
                                           ↑
                                           Uppercase S
```

All file paths are either absolute paths, or are implicitly relative to the current directory.  You don’t need all those lines dealing with `currentRelativePath`.  Just write this:

```
String curDir = "src";
```